# Error: Product validation failed: path: Path `path` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I keep getting this error message whenever i try to populate my "product" page from MongoDB.
I have added the body-parser dependency.
N.B
I stored the product images in my Public folder and i am storing the imagePath in MongoDB.
Here's a snippet of my code

From my App.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const ejs = require('ejs');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
    const Product = require('./models/products');
```

From my product Model...

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const productSchema = new Schema({
      path: {
        type: String, 
        required: true 
      },
    
      title: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
      },
      price: {
        type: Number, 
        required: true
      },
    },
    {timestamps : true});
    
    const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
    
    module.exports = Product;

Also from my App.js files
```

```
app.get('/product/create', (req, res) => {
  
  res.render('upload', { title: 'Add Products'});
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
})

//Looping through all products
app.get('/product', (req, res) => { 
  Product.find().sort({ createdAt: -1})
  .then((result) => {
   res.render('product', { title: 'All Products', products : result})
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
});

//POST request to product route
app.post('/product', (req, res) => {
  const product = new Product(req.body);

  product.save()
  .then((result) => {
    res.redirect('/product');
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: What is the value of req.body ?

Comment: It returns what is expected 
  imagePath: '/img/heuwinesWatch.jpg',
  title: "Heuwines's Designer Watches",
  price: '100'

Comment: Ok that's cool, but the field in your model is call `path` not `imagePath`